# How to wrap a string

Tags: java, string

I have a very long string like "The event for mobile" they can be any length strings ,i want to show .... after say certain length ,how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
    String str = "The event for mobile is here";
    String temp = "";
    if(str !=null && str.length() > 10) {
        temp = str.substring(0, 10) + "...."; // here 0 is start index and 10 is last index
    } else {
        temp = str;
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
```

output would be - The event ....

Answer (score 4):

Use Apache Common library's [WordUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) class.

```
static String wrap(java.lang.String str, 
       int wrapLength, java.lang.String newLineStr, boolean wrapLongWords)
```

example -

```
    String str = "This is a sentence that we're using to test the wrap method";
    System.out.println("Original String 1:\n" + str);
    System.out.println("\nWrap length of 10:\n" + WordUtils.wrap(str, 10));
    System.out.println("\nWrap length of 20:\n" + WordUtils.wrap(str, 20));
    System.out.println("\nWrap length of 30:\n" + WordUtils.wrap(str, 30));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String template = "Hello I Am A Very Long String";
System.out.println(template.length() > 10 ? template.substring(0, 10) + "..." : template);
```

You can just look at the length and then do a `substring`.

Or if you can use Apache's common Util then use this [WordUtils.wrap()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html).

I didn't do a good search earlier, [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-character-word-wise-in-java) is exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want full words then do this:

```
public static void shortenStringFullWords(String str, int maxLength) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String[] tokens = str.split(" ");
    for (String token: tokens) {
        if (output.length() + token.length <= maxLength - 3) {
            output.append(token);
            output.append(" ");
        } else {
            return output.toString().trim() + "...";
        }
    }
    return output.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this

```
    String longString = "lorem ipusum ver long string";
    String shortString = "";
    int maxLength = 5;
    if(longString != null && longString.length() > maxLength) {
        shortString = longString.substring(0,maxLength - 1)+"...";
    }
```

Here, you can change maxLength to your desired number.

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString ="my lengthy string";
    int startIndex=0, endIndex=myString.length(), lengthLimit = 10;



    while(startIndex<endIndex) {
        System.out.println(myString.substring(startIndex,  startIndex+lengthLimit));
        startIndex = startIndex+lengthLimit+1;
    }
```