# cut string in java without breaking the middle of word

Tags: java, android, regex

How can i truncate a text whithout cut in the middle of a word?

For exemple, I have the string :

> "A totally fresh and new approach to life itself emerges. Once again,
>   you’re off to a good start, willing to do that little bit extra in
>   your result-oriented frame of mind. It’s not the amount of effort but
>   the results that matter to you. You also gain much in the depth of the
>   romance and emotional bonds in your life. This is a good time for
>   self-improvement programs or philanthropy, alms-giving and charity."

If i cut it, i want to cut like this :

> "A totally fresh and new approach to life itself emerges. Once again,
>   you’re off to a good start, willing to do that little bit extra in
>   your result-oriented frame of mind. It’s not the amount of effort but
>   the results that matter to you. You also gain much in the depth of the
>   romance and"

And not :

> "A totally fresh and new approach to life itself emerges. Once again,
>   you’re off to a good start, willing to do that little bit extra in
>   your result-oriented frame of mind. It’s not the amount of effort but
>   the results that matter to you. You also gain much in the depth of the
>   romance and emoti"

Comment: Where do you want to cut ? How do you determine that ? Do you know the index where to cut ?

Comment: This question has been asked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-character-word-wise-in-java

Comment: If so just check at the index and move it backwards or forwards to the next whitespace.

Comment: Shouldn't `ellipsed` do this for you?

Comment: I think he is asking about `substring()` or wrapping ! I'm confused.

Comment: i have to fit it in the textview.like this way                       for (int i = 0; i < totalLine-2; i++) {
            // Get No of characters fit in that textView
int number= holder.txtitem_description.getPaint().breakText(textToBeShown, 0, textToBeShown.length(), true,
              holder.txtitem_description.getWidth()-holder.txtitem_description.getPaddingLeft()-holder.txtitem_description.getPaddingRight(), null);
         
     // Update the text to show next
textToBeShownintext+=textToBeShown.substring(0, number);
textToBeShown = textToBeShown.substring(number,textToBeShown.length()); }

Comment: @the new ldiot so i know the index where to cut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this method pass your string and last index till you want to trancate.

```
public String truncate(final String content, final int lastIndex) {
    String result = content.substring(0, lastIndex);
    if (content.charAt(lastIndex) != ' ') {
        result = result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf(" "));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1. Nice and clear. :)

Comment: I wonder why there is no lib yet. Its a common problem.

Answer (score 3):

[`WordUtils.wrap(String str, int wrapLength)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

This will cut the String in the middle (more or less).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "A totally fresh and new approach to life itself emerges. Once again, you’re off to a good start, willing to do that little bit extra in your result-oriented frame of mind. It’s not the amount of effort but the results that matter to you. You also gain much in the depth of the romance and emotional bonds in your life. This is a good time for self-improvement programs or philanthropy, alms-giving and charity.";
    int middle = s.length() / 2;
    while(s.charAt(middle) != ' ') {
        middle++;
    }
    String start = s.substring(0, middle);
    String end = s.substring(middle, s.length());
    System.out.println(start);
    System.out.println(end);
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `String s = "A totally";` ?

Comment: Nope, but I can imagine the result. It only depends on what you want to achieve. The question is not clear and I just gave a solution. You can then adjust the code. (personally I like more the @Ashish Aggarwal solution)