# Turning a long string into a paragraph in console in Java

Tags: java, string, indentation, paragraph

In Java, I want to print a rather long String to the console, but instead of having it printed as one really long line, I'd like to turn it into a nicely formatted paragraph.

So example:

```
String something = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
```

Would print as

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
```

But I would like something like this

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
```

How to make new lines where appropriate without having to do it manually with \n?

Comment: Define _appropriate_.

Comment: This question has the appropriate answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-character-word-wise-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-character-word-wise-in-java

Comment: What's wrong with `\n`?

Comment: Appropriate could be at every period "." or after a certain number of characters.

Nothing is wrong with \n, but I don't want to place them manually in my very long strings.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String msg="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
String h[]=msg.split("0", 2);
System.out.println(h[0]+"0"+"\n"+h[1]);
```

or use this

```
  String h[]=msg.split("0", 2);
  System.out.println(h[0]+"0");
  System.out.println(h[1]);
```

Comment: This works only for the given example, the question is more generic. OP wants an answer that’d work for *any* long string.