# How to wordwrap content in JTable? Java Swing

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I am generating JTable by hardcoding.

I need to make my content in JTable to be wordwrapped to avoid overflowing text being hidden.

Image attached (for instance, the text in [2][3]):

[image]

Your reply is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this link: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-characters-word-wise-in-java)

Comment: You need a table cell render. In that you  change the text to html with paragraph tags for line endings. You also need to adjust the height of the table row